# ASP.NET MVC Forms authentication is causing login url to be called twice

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

We have a new project which is very bare bones at the moment.

I'm setting up forms auth and have the following views:

```
views/home/index.cshtml
views/logon/index.cshtml
```

and in my `web.config` I have the following:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/LogOn/Dev" />
</authentication>
```

If this is enabled the action for login is called twice.

If I comment it out it is only called once?

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a controller called logon? Typically you see something like an account controller which has an action for logon, register, change password, etc.

Comment: this is for an intranet application. in general the users security is chained in using some jiggery pockery - this is for us devs to be able to log in without using the ldap search.

Comment: Can you show the basic outline of the code used in the Action. What Return type are you using in the action, perhaps a `return RedirectToAction(` or similar? And are you performing the Post with a standard web form or an AJAX request?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to tell without the action method but if it looks something like this...

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult External()
        {
            var authentication = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
            if (Request.HttpMethod == "POST")
            {
                foreach (var key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
                {
                    if (key.StartsWith("submit.External.") && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Form.Get(key)))
                    {
                        var authType = key.Substring("submit.External.".Length);
                        authentication.Challenge(authType);
                        return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
                    }
                }
            }
            var identity = authentication.AuthenticateAsync("External").Result.Identity;
            if (identity != null)
            {
                authentication.SignOut("External");
                authentication.SignIn(
                    new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = true },
                    new ClaimsIdentity(identity.Claims, "Application", identity.NameClaimType, identity.RoleClaimType));
                return Redirect(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]);
            }

            return View();
        }
```

... then HttpUnauthorizedResult() is called and this method looks for a ReturnUrl query string key/value pair. If it doesn't exist, then it cycles through again, appending the current URL as for the value in this pair on the second run, effectively calling the method twice.

In order to avoid, supply a valid ReturnUrl key value pair in the query string like this...

```
<a href="/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=@ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.PathAndQuery">Login to Your App</a>
```

Note that the key is case sensitive. If you use ReturnURL for example, the method will still be called twice.